# homological 2 dimensional groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology

In a  Commentarii Mathematici Helvetici paper  by Benno Eckman  and Heinz  Müller in  1980 (volume  50,  pages 510-520) proved  that poincaré Duality  Groups  of  dimension 2  with  positive first Betti  number  are  surface  groups.

Is  there any  development  into  proving  that certain groups  of   (homological) or  geometric dimension  2  are surface  groups?

Comment: The term is "homological dimension 2", where "homological" qualifies "dimension". So "homological 2 dimensional" and "homologic dimension 2" both sound weird.

Comment: It is very unclear what exactly your question is. It is known that PD(2) groups over Z are surface groups; it is also known that PD(2) groups over other "reasonable" commutative rings are virtually surface groups. No need to assume nontriviality of the 1st betti number. What are the "certain" groups you are interested in?

Comment: Dear  Misha, I  would  like  to  know  a  reference  for  the  result  without  the  1st  Betti  number  assumption,  both over  $\mathbb{Z}$ and for  the  "virtual" statement for   "reasonable" commutative  rings. Thanks a  lot in  advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See my paper with Bruce Kleiner "Geometry of quasiplanes" for general unital commutative rings, it also contains a reference to the paper by Eckmann  and Linnell from 1983 where they prove the theorem for PD(2) groups over Z and to the one by Bowditch which works over Q.